# block comments not automatically indented in Neovim

Tags: neovim, indentation, comments

When inserting a block comment in a (TypeScript) buffer in Neovim, the line after the `/**<Return>` is not automatically indented. How can I achieve the expected behavior described below?

### Neovim

```
NVIM v0.7.2
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by brew@BigSur
```

### expected behavior

```
function f() {
  /**<hit return>
   * <cursor is here>
  return 0;
}
```

### actual behavior

```
function f() {
  /**<hit return>
* <cursor is here>
  return 0;
}
```

### (potentially) relevant option states

```
:verbose set autoindent? smartindent? cindent? cinkeys? indentexpr? comments? fo-table?
  autoindent
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim line 51
nosmartindent
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.7.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/indent/typescript.vim line 16
nocindent
  cinkeys=0{,0},0),0],:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
  indentexpr=nvim_treesitter#indent()
        Last set from Lua
  comments=sO:* -,mO:*  ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,f://
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim line 187
  formatoptions=cro/n
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim line 186
E488: Trailing characters: fo-table?
```

### init.vim

```
autocmd!
scriptencoding utf-8
if !1 | finish | endif

set nocompatible
set number
syntax enable
set fileencodings=utf-8,sjis,euc-jp,latin
set encoding=utf-8
set title
set background=dark
set nobackup
set hlsearch
set showcmd
set cmdheight=1
set laststatus=2
set scrolloff=10
set expandtab
set shell=fish
set backupskip=/tmp/*,/private/tmp/*

if has('nvim')
  set inccommand=split
endif

set t_BE=

set nosc noru nosm
set lazyredraw
set ignorecase
set smarttab
filetype plugin indent on
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set autoindent
set smartindent
set nowrap "No Wrap lines
set backspace=start,eol,indent
set path+=**
set wildignore+=*/node_modules/*

set number

autocmd InsertLeave * set nopaste

set shortmess=I

set cursorline

highlight Visual cterm=NONE ctermbg=236 ctermfg=NONE guibg=Grey40

highlight LineNr cterm=none ctermfg=240 guifg=#2b506e guibg=#000000

augroup BgHighlight
  autocmd!
  autocmd WinEnter * set cul
  autocmd WinLeave * set nocul
augroup END

if &term =~ "screen"
  autocmd BufEnter * if bufname("") !~ "^?[A-Za-z0-9?]*://" | silent! exe '!echo -n "\ek[`hostname`:`basename $PWD`/`basename %`]\e\\"' | endif
  autocmd VimLeave * silent!  exe '!echo -n "\ek[`hostname`:`basename $PWD`]\e\\"'
endif

au BufNewFile,BufRead * if !expand('%:t') | setlocal shiftwidth=4 | endif
au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &syntax == '' | setlocal shiftwidth=4 | endif
au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &buftype == '' | setlocal shiftwidth=4 | endif

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.es6 setf javascript
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tsx setf typescriptreact
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.md set filetype=markdown
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.mdx set filetype=markdown
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.flow set filetype=javascript
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.fish set filetype=fish

set suffixesadd=.js,.es,.jsx,.json,.css,.less,.sass,.styl,.php,.py,.md

autocmd FileType json setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
autocmd FileType typescriptreact setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
autocmd FileType typescript setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
autocmd FileType markdown setlocal shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4
autocmd FileType sql setlocal shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4
autocmd FileType vue setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
autocmd FileType html setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
autocmd FileType css setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2

runtime ./plug.vim
if has("unix")
  let s:uname = system("uname -s")
  " Do Mac stuff
  if s:uname == "Darwin\n"
    runtime ./macos.vim
  endif
endif
if has('win32')
  runtime ./windows.vim
endif

runtime ./maps.vim
runtime ./commands.vim

if exists("&termguicolors") && exists("&winblend")
  syntax enable
  set termguicolors
  set winblend=0
  set wildoptions=pum
  set pumblend=5
  set background=dark
  " Use NeoSolarized
  let g:neosolarized_termtrans=1
  runtime ./colors/NeoSolarized.vim
  colorscheme NeoSolarized
endif

autocmd BufEnter * lua vim.diagnostic.disable()

set exrc
set signcolumn=yes
set clipboard+=unnamedplus

au Filetype * set formatoptions=cro/n
au Filetype * set comments-=:// comments+=f://

let g:vimwiki_key_mappings =
  \ {
  \   'all_maps': 1,
  \   'global': 1,
  \   'headers': 1,
  \   'text_objs': 1,
  \   'table_format': 1,
  \   'table_mappings': 0,
  \   'lists': 1,
  \   'links': 1,
  \   'html': 1,
  \   'mouse': 0,
  \ }
```

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-). Could you tell what is the filetype of your buffer? What is the result of the `:set ft?`?

Comment: From the content of your file I have supposed your buffer type is lua. Using Neovim 0.8.2 I fail to reproduce your problem. But `indentexpr` is set to `GetLuaIndent()`

Comment: You want to use `:setlocal` in the last command there to make sure you are not looking at the global options, I think.

Comment: the filetype of my buffer is TypeScript

Comment: I tried `setlocal comments` and `setlocal formatoptions` but got the same behavior.

Comment: I just added my init.vim to this post

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble I misunderstood what you said at first. I get the same results from running `:setlocal option? ...`. Please ignore https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/40183/block-comments-not-automatically-indented-in-neovim#comment73627_40183